# Is it OK return http status 404 in the POST?

Tags: rest, http, post

I'm developing an API and I always try to use the most correct http status codes for each scenario.

One of this scenarios is the response for POST requests. Per example, a POST method for an endpoint `/orders/` receive some informations, like a `customer`:

```
{
  customerDocument: {number: "123.456.789"},
  // other informations for create a order
}
```

So, my questions is: if this `number` from `customerDocument` not exists, is it Ok to return a **404** status code error with a nice message telling that the customer was not found?

I normally use 404 only for GET in the specific resources (the most obvious usage), like:

```
/customers/{number}/
```

In business validations like "The customer is not active", I normally use the http status code 422 for any http method (POST, PUT, GET, etc). I'm in doubt if I can use 404 or 422 for my POST example.

Comment: I tend to follow this table http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think `400` is the appropriate status code in this scenario, given its definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors):

> **400 Bad Request**
>
> The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error.

According to the [description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors), semantically, `422` is better (*"The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors."*). However, `422` is introduced for WebDAV, so it is better to use general purpose status code such as `400`.

`400` is not the perfect status code, as whether document number exists or valid is not so *apparent*. However, excludes special-purpose status code such as `422`, `400` is the best option.

**Why `404` is not appropriate?**

From RESTful API point of view, endpoint `/orders/` is a resource, no matter it accepts `GET` or `POST` or something else. `404` is only appropriate when the resource `/orders/` itself does not exist. If `/orders/` endpoint exist, but its invocation failed (no matter what reasons), the response status code must be something  other than `404`.

Comment: 412 Precondition Failed is not appropriate unless the client has defined the precondition in the headers.  You should remove that part of your answer.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Thanks for your suggestion, introducing `412` do make things complicated and confusing. I'll remove it from my answer.

Comment: @shaochuancs about the 404, I agree! But the 400 not appear the best option. Normally, the people understand 400 as a syntax or type error in the request. As described in the Wikipedia link: "e.g., malformed request syntax, size too large, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing". In RestEasy framework, 400 is used for this cases, for example.

Comment: @Dherik yes, 400 is not perfect. But after check all response code, I can't find a code better than it.

Comment: Hi, your comment on 404 in inaccurate. if the endpoint /orders does not exist that is 404, that part is right, but if the order 123 does not exist and user calls /orders/123, that is also a 404. @Dherik should be returning 404 as the response for the scenario he is asking about